# Clueless as to how to solve this gamma function differential inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, factorial, gamma-function, functional-inequalities

Use the conventions $\Pi(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$ and $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\Pi(x)=\Pi^{(n)}(x)$ henceforth.

> I am trying to evaluate for what real $\color{blue}{x}>2$ it holds that $$\frac{\Pi^{(\color{red}{n})}(\color{blue}{x})}{\Pi(\color{red}{n})}>1$$

The only helpful information about expanding the ratio is a function defined recursively as $$P(n,x)=\frac{d \ln[\Pi(x)]}{dx} \,P(n-1,x)+\left.\frac{\partial P(n,x)}{\partial x}\right|_{(n-1,x)} = \frac{\Pi^{(n)}(x)}{\Pi(x)}$$ given that $P(0,u)=1$ (very special thanks to @SimplyBeautifulArt for helping me with this).

I have absolutely no clue what to do from here. How should I proceed?

<sub>(Please note that this isn’t a homework problem, just a small piece of a more thorough investigation that I am conducting independently.)</sub>

Comment: $\frac{\Pi^{(n)}(x)}{\Pi( \color{red}{n})} $ or $\frac{\Pi^{(n)}(x)}{\Pi( \color{blue}{x})} $ ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit The first

Comment: It took me a while to notice the difference between the statement of the question & the next equation ... I was figuring the latter ... I've got it now ... & the colouring in your edit is working fine for me $\ddot \smile$